# Drywall Joints sealing & Torn Insulation facing

Tags: insulation, patching-drywall

I am a newbie and recently bought a house. We removed a portion of the drywall in the kitchen for some remodel work. I have two questions about this.

1. I observed that at some places the insulation does not have this brown cover which acts as a vapor barrier. I checked & made sure that wherever it's missing it's not on the other side of the wall. I am wondering if I should cover it and if yes what would be the right product to use? I live in MI if that matters.
2. When I hang the drywall, should the edges of the two drywalls pieces be sealed using mud or something else?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for your county under [IRC N1101.7](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-11-re-energy-efficiency#IRC2021P2_Pt04_Ch11_SecN1101.7), and write down your climate zone. Now go to [IRC R702.7](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-7-wall-covering#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch07_SecR702.7) and look in Table R702.7(2) for your permitted vapor retarder classes. Table R702.7(1) will tell you what can be used for your vapor barrier.

When you're mudding drywall, any sealing is incidental. The purpose of the mud is to make a smooth surface that looks nice and to stiffen the drywall joints between studs. If you intend to install tile over the joints between studs, the mud will prevent the drywall to one side of the joint from flexing independent of the other side of the joint, so taping joints is still necessary. Alternatively I suppose you could install blocking below each joint and use screws to achieve the same end. The mud sounds cheaper and easier.